# Plot ellipse from rectangle

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, plot

I have been looking all over the Web for a way to plot an ellipse from rectangle coordinates, that is, top-left corner (x, y) and size (width and height). The only ones I can find everywhere are based on the Midpoint/Bresenham algorithm and I can't use that because when working with integer pixels, I lose precisions because these algorithms use a center point and radials.

The ellipse MUST be limited to the rectangle's coordinates, so if I feed it a rectangle where the width and height are 4 (or any even number), I should get an ellipse that completely fits in a 4x4 rectangle, and not one that will be 5x5 (like what those algorithms are giving me).

Does anyone know of any way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, given a bounding box, you want the largest ellipse bounded by that box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not get the width and height (divided by 2) and center of the rectangle then plug that into any ellipse drawing routine as its major, minor axis and center?  I guess I'm not seeing the problem all the way here.

Comment: No, I can't, because for even width and height the resulting ellipse's width and height will be incremented by one pixel from the original, seeing as it plots the pixel at center + axis and center - axis. I need it to be perfectly within the bounds, my "pixels" are 32x32 so this is very visible.

Comment: So the problem is sub pixel accuracy and reflecting about the quadrants is causing an overwrite on some edges.  Given that, you should be able to store a non-integer width height (or at least a fixed point value with 1 bit for fraction) to handle this.  

Then the problem is finding or writing an ellipse generator that works with non integer widths and heights.  That shouldn't be too difficult to find, but I haven't looked so perhaps not?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need.  Here is my solution with code.  The error is at most half a pixel.

[image: ellipses size 1 to 10]

I based my solution on the [McIlroy ellipse algorithm](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/155.pdf), an integer-only algorithm which McIlroy mathematically proved to be accurate to a half-pixel, without missing or extra points, and correctly drawing degenerate cases such as lines and circles.  [L. Patrick](http://enchantia.com/graphapp/doc/tech/ellipses.html) further analyzed McIlroy's algorithm, including ways to optimize it and how a filled ellipse can be broken up into rectangles.

McIlroy's algorithm traces a path through one quadrant of the ellipse; the remaining quadrants are rendered through symmetry.  Each step in the path requires three comparisons.  Many of the other ellipse algorithms use octants instead, which require only two comparisons per step.  However, octant-based methods have are notoriously inaccurate at the octant boundaries.  The slight savings of one comparison is not worth the inaccuracy of the octant methods.

Like virtually every other integer ellipse algorithm, McIlroy's wants the *center* at integer coordinates, and the lengths of the axes `a` and `b` to be integers as well.  However, we want to be able to draw an ellipse with a bounding box using any integer coordinates.  A bounding box with an even width or even height will have a center on an integer-and-a-half coordinate, and `a` or `b` will be an integer-and-a-half.

My solution was to perform calculations using integers that are *double* of what is needed.  Any variable starting with `q` is calculated from double pixel values.  An even `q` variable is on an integer coordinate, and an odd `q` variable is at an integer-and-a-half coordinate.  I then re-worked McIroy's math to get the correct mathematical expressions with these new doubled values.  This includes modifying starting values when the bounding box has even width or height.

Behold, the subroutine/method `drawEllipse` given below.  You provide it with the integer coordinates (`x0`,`y0`) and (`x1`,`y1`) of the bounding box.  It doesn't care if `x0` < `x1` versus `x0` > `x1`; it will swap them as needed.  If you provide `x0` == `x1`, your will get a vertical line.  Similarly for the `y0` and `y1` coordinates.  You also provide the boolean `fill` parameter, which draws only the ellipse outline if false, and draws a filled ellipse if true.  You also have to provide the subroutines `drawPoint(x, y)` which draws a single point and `drawRow(xleft, xright, y)` which draws a horizontal line from `xleft` to `xright` inclusively.

McIlroy and Patrick optimize their code to fold constants, reuse common subexpressions, etc.  For clarity, I didn't do that.  Most compilers do this automatically today anyway.

```
void drawEllipse(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, boolean fill)
{
    int xb, yb, xc, yc;


    // Calculate height
    yb = yc = (y0 + y1) / 2;
    int qb = (y0 < y1) ? (y1 - y0) : (y0 - y1);
    int qy = qb;
    int dy = qb / 2;
    if (qb % 2 != 0)
        // Bounding box has even pixel height
        yc++;

    // Calculate width
    xb = xc = (x0 + x1) / 2;
    int qa = (x0 < x1) ? (x1 - x0) : (x0 - x1);
    int qx = qa % 2;
    int dx = 0;
    long qt = (long)qa*qa + (long)qb*qb -2L*qa*qa*qb;
    if (qx != 0) {
        // Bounding box has even pixel width
        xc++;
        qt += 3L*qb*qb;
    }

    // Start at (dx, dy) = (0, b) and iterate until (a, 0) is reached
    while (qy >= 0 && qx <= qa) {
        // Draw the new points
        if (!fill) {
        drawPoint(xb-dx, yb-dy);
        if (dx != 0 || xb != xc) {
            drawPoint(xc+dx, yb-dy);
            if (dy != 0 || yb != yc)
            drawPoint(xc+dx, yc+dy);
        }
        if (dy != 0 || yb != yc)
            drawPoint(xb-dx, yc+dy);
        }

        // If a (+1, 0) step stays inside the ellipse, do it
        if (qt + 2L*qb*qb*qx + 3L*qb*qb <= 0L || 
            qt + 2L*qa*qa*qy - (long)qa*qa <= 0L) {
            qt += 8L*qb*qb + 4L*qb*qb*qx;
            dx++;
            qx += 2;
        // If a (0, -1) step stays outside the ellipse, do it
        } else if (qt - 2L*qa*qa*qy + 3L*qa*qa > 0L) {
            if (fill) {
                drawRow(xb-dx, xc+dx, yc+dy);
                if (dy != 0 || yb != yc)
                    drawRow(xb-dx, xc+dx, yb-dy);
            }
            qt += 8L*qa*qa - 4L*qa*qa*qy;
            dy--;
            qy -= 2;
        // Else step (+1, -1)
        } else {
            if (fill) {
                drawRow(xb-dx, xc+dx, yc+dy);
                if (dy != 0 || yb != yc)
                    drawRow(xb-dx, xc+dx, yb-dy);
            }
            qt += 8L*qb*qb + 4L*qb*qb*qx + 8L*qa*qa - 4L*qa*qa*qy;
            dx++;
            qx += 2;
            dy--;
            qy -= 2;
        }
    }   // End of while loop
    return;
}
```

The image above shows the output for all bounding boxes up to size 10x10.  I also ran the algorithm for all ellipses up to size 100x100.  This produced 384614 points in the first quadrant.  The error between where each of these points were plotted and where the actual ellipse occurs was calculated.  The maximum error was 0.500000 (half a pixel) and the average error among all of the points was 0.216597.

Comment: In case anyone gets weird results on the filled variant, you may need to check your drawRow parameters. If the third param in your horizontal-line-draw function is the length of the line, then you need to supply the following as the value for the third param:  `dx * 2 + (even_pixel_width ? 2 : 1)`. Finally, create a bool `even_pixel_width` at the beginning of the function, initialize to false, and then add `even_pixel_width=true` below `if (qx != 0)`

Comment: @deLock: No need for any of that.  The third parameter to `drawRow` is the y-coordinate of the row, not its width.  Adjustments for an even pixel width are already in the code; there is no need to create a boolean flag for that.

Comment: DrSheldon, please read my comment carefully. You missed this part: "*If the third param in your horizontal-line-draw function is the length of the line*". In that case your code will not work correctly. The formal params for drawRow are not defined in your post. I verified all of the above practically, so no worries.

Comment: BTW, it is kind of surprising that I had to add (even_pixel_width ? 2 : 1) pixels to the width to make both the filled and unfilled code render the same actual width of the ellipse. Just to double check -- did you compare the widths of the filled vs unfilled rendered ellipse when the caller specifies even vs odd width? You might find the same discrepancy as I did -- the filled one was 1 pixel narrower than the unfilled one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this problem was to draw the closest smaller ellipse with odd dimensions, but pulled apart by a pixel along the even length dimension, repeating the middle pixels.

This can be done easily by using different middle points for the quadrants when plotting each pixel:

```
DrawPixel(midX_high + x, midY_high + y);
DrawPixel(midX_low  - x, midY_high + y);
DrawPixel(midX_high + x, midY_low  - y);
DrawPixel(midX_low  - x, midY_low  - y);
```

The high values are the ceil'ed midpoint, and the low values are the floored midpoint.

An image to illustrate, ellipses with width 15 and 16:

[image: ellipses]